# RSPS server error after editing 2 items

Tags: java

### Hi I edited the stats of 2 items in my rsps  (purple phat and ice arrows) and now I get this error when running the source:

```
Your server is now online.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17
        at ItemHandler.loadItemList(ItemHandler.java:283)
        at ItemHandler.<init>(ItemHandler.java:173)
        at server.main(server.java:165)
```

---

And I cant connect to it, theres TONS of code but ill copy and paste where i mainly edited

First I edited the ice arrow to 200 bonus

```
item = 77   Khali_brew  A_bottle_of_Khazard's_worst_brew.   4.67264229473597    4.67264229473597    4.85427038587765    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 78   Ice_arrows  Can_be_fired_with_yew_or_magic_bows_and_d_bow.  50000000    50000000    50000000    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   200 0   0
item = 79   Ice_arrow_4 It's_a_Ice_arrow_4  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 80   Ice_arrow_3 It's_a_Ice_arrow_3  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 81   Ice_arrow_2 It's_a_Ice_arrow_2  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 82   Ice_arrow_5 It's_a_Ice_arrow_5  50000000    50000000    50000000    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

then I edited the purple partyhat but I changed it back after but Ill show you what it looks like so you can make sure their is no errors around it

```
item = 1040 Yellow_partyhat A_nice_hat_from_a_cracker.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1041 Yellow_partyhat Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_Yellow_partyhat.   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1042 Blue_partyhat   A_nice_hat_from_a_cracker.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1043 Blue_partyhat   Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_Blue_partyhat. 1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1044 Green_partyhat  A_nice_hat_from_a_cracker.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1045 Green_partyhat  Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_Green_partyhat.    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1046 Purple_partyhat A_nice_hat_from_a_cracker.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1047 Purple_partyhat Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_Purple_partyhat.   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1048 White_partyhat  A_nice_hat_from_a_cracker.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1049 White_partyhat  Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_White_partyhat.    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1050 Santa_hat   It's_a_Santa_hat.   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1051 Santa_hat   Swap_this_note_at_any_bank_for_a_Santa_hat. 1   100000  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
item = 1052 Cape_of_legends The_cape_worn_by_members_of_the_Legends_Guild.  348.004635307775    348.004635307775    402.20768830689 0   0   0   0   0   7   7   7   7   7   0   0
item = 1053 Green_h'ween_mask   Aaaarrrghhh_..._I'm_a_monster.  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I cant really paste the whole file.. its reallllyyyy long

If you find any errors please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Line 1046 has one too few items.  That would likely be the cause of your arrays being badly formed.